# How to find maximum value with date in each month in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sum, max

I am seeking answer to the question that has two parts. In part A: I would like to construct a data frame of the maximum value of total_precip (variable in my data frame) in each month with year, month, and day of its occurrence. In part B: I wanted to have another data frame where I can have the maximum cumulative total_precip for consecutive two day (i.e., sum of total_precip of two consecutive days higher than any other two days) in each month with dates and corresponding values. For example, if the sum of total_precip on Jan 10 and 11 is higher than any other two consecutive day of the month, the dates (year, month and corresponding days) along with its value will be stored in the data frame for each month of the year.

Here is the code that I started to do part A but this gives me only the maximum value in each month without specifying which day that maximum value has occurred.

```
library(weathercan)
library(tidyverse)
DF = weather_dl(station_ids = 2925, start = "1990-01-01", end = "1995-12-31", interval = "day")[,c(11,12,13,14,32)]
DF$month = as.numeric(DF$month)
DF$day = as.numeric(DF$day)
MaxValWithDate = DF %>% group_by(year, month) %>% summarise(MaxVal = max(total_precip))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `slice` for part A:

```
DF %>%
    group_by(year, month) %>%
    slice(which.max(total_precip))

 #   date       year  month   day total_precip
 #   <date>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
 # 1 1990-01-28 1990      1    28          7.8
 # 2 1990-02-21 1990      2    21          4.8
 # 3 1990-03-12 1990      3    12         49.2
 # ....
```

And then we can use the `lead` function along with `slice` again for part B:

```
DF %>%
    group_by(year, month) %>%
    mutate(lead_total_precip = lead(total_precip),
           lead_day = lead(date)) %>%
    mutate(cumu_precip = total_precip + lead_total_precip)  %>%
    slice(which.max(cumu_precip))

   # date       year  month   day total_precip lead_total_precip lead_day   cumu_precip
   # <date>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>             <dbl> <date>           <dbl>
   # 1 1990-01-28 1990      1    28          7.8               5.2 1990-01-29        13  
   # 2 1990-02-21 1990      2    21          4.8               1.8 1990-02-22         6.6
   # 3 1990-03-11 1990      3    11          0                49.2 1990-03-12        49.2
   # ....
```

The resulting data.frames should have all the information you need, then you can use the `select` function to keep only the columns you need.

Comment: Thanks. The first part works like a charm. the second part is fine, however, I would like to have the date of both days in the data frame that when added produces maximum precipitation. Right now if you look at the date and month column- it shows single value (although the value of the lead day is added and shown in the lead_day column. I wanted to have dates for both days without adding the total_precipation but rather having the dates of the precipitation of two consecutive days that has the maximum total_precip. Does this make sense? Thank you

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Perhaps you should post an example of your desired output in your question.

Comment: The desired output should be like `DesiredOutput = data.frame(date = c("1990-01-28","1990-01-29","1990-02-21","1990-02-22","1990-03-11","1990-03-12"),
                           year = c(1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990), month = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), day = c(28,29,21,22,11,12), 
                           total_precip = c(7.8,5.2,4.8,1.8,0,49.2))`

Comment: Also, how if I would like to gather the dates and value of the cumulative total_precipitation for consecutive 5 days instead two days? I tried to modify the earlier response like `DF %>%
    group_by(year, month) %>%
    mutate(lead_total_precip = lead(total_precip,4),
           lead_day = lead(date,4)) %>%
    mutate(cumu_precip = total_precip + lead_total_precip)  %>%
    slice(which.max(cumu_precip))` but it would add the fifth day to the calculation rather adding all the five days total_precip.

Comment: The functions in the __`zoo`__ package might help you with that (i.e. [rollsum](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-6/topics/rollmean))